# Javascript: print html as plain text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print plain html from javascript and can't figured out how to do so. 
Example:

```
$('#elem').html('This is a normal string'); // --> This is a normal string

$('#elem').html('This <b>contains</b> html')
//Current-> This contains html   (contains is bold)
//Wanted-> This <b>contains</b> html
```

I want to do this because I'm working with comments written by users and don't want html tags to apply if they put some in their comments. But for other reasons I need to see the tags.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `.text` instead of `.html`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$('#elem').text('This <b>contains</b> html');
```

Related Snippet:

```js
$('#an-id').text('<b>I don\'t want this to be HTML</b>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="an-id">This is not HTML!</p>
```

Good luck!

Check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [***`.text()`***](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, which automatically escapes HTML to text for you!

In this example it is:

```
$('#elem').text('This <b>contains</b> html')
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use the jQuery [**`.text()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp) method.

```
$('#elem').text('This <b>contains</b> html');
```

**example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#elem").text('This <b>contains</b> html');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Click ME!!</button>

<p id="elem">This is a paragraph.</p>
   
</body>
</html>
```